# How to check the password of protected post in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I have a protected post with a password.

I would like to check if the password sends is good in **ajax.**

HTML :

```
<form class="protected-post-form" action=".../wp-pass.php" method="post">
   <input name="post_password" id="pwbox-4470" type="password" size="20">
   <input type="submit" class="send" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

jQuery :

```
$("input.send").live("click", function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: ".../wp-pass.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      // show content
    }
  });
});
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the server. The server will have to return some kind of error to let you know that there's a problem with the password and you will need to handle it. A status code of 403 would be appropriate for an incorrect password, but there's no guarantee that any particular server will return that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused - the post is not protected with a password, it just happens to include one in the submitted form.

Server side you check it as you would check any other form variable posted. `$_POST["pwbox-4470"]` will contain the password you have submitted server side.

You need to ensure the form is served over HTTPS to ensure the password isn't transmitted in plain text.

Comment: Thanks Ross, but consider that my article **#4470** is protected with a password `azerty`. On the page **#4470**, I have the form with input password. How to check the value `$_POST["pwbox-4470"]` is equal to `azerty` ?

Comment: You could have a service that takes a page number, and a password - if the password matches for the page number then return the data.

Comment: yeah, but how to get "azerty" in server side ? Because I don't know what it is here.

Comment: Have you written PHP before? Since you were posting back to a php page I assumed you were - what technology are you going to use server side?

Comment: Yes, I use Wordpress, I use PHP and I use jQuery. But how get the value `azerty` ? If it had been a custom field, I could did for example : `<?php get_post_meta(4470, "password", true); ?>`, but here I don't know.

Comment: '<?php if($_POST=='azerty'){get_post_meta(4470, "password", true);} ?>' would be my guess - I'm not a PHP programmer but the should work.